# In Operator-SDK, Several Patch in one reconcile function

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, operator-sdk

I'm working on implementing operator with operator-sdk.

I have some questions about `Patch` API in operator SDK(`client.Client`).

There are two Patch API which are `Client.Patch` and `Client.Status().Patch`.

As far as I know, first one(`Client.Patch`) would be role as patch fields except `Status` in resource. The other one(`Client.Status().Patch`) would patch `Status` field in resource.

In this point, Can I use `Patch`(Whatever it is `Client.Status().Patch` or `Client.Patch`) API several times in one Reconcile function?

I thought that `Patch` API would change resource version so API cannot work well when I called `Patch` API several time in one Reconcile function, however APIs(`Patch`) works well(I actually invoked 2times in one Reconcile function) as I observed.

If there is knowledge which I misunderstood, give me advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a blog post with title: [7 Best Practices for Writing Kubernetes Operators: An SRE Perspective](https://www.openshift.com/blog/7-best-practices-for-writing-kubernetes-operators-an-sre-perspective)

And 4th point is:

> #### 4: One Custom Resource Modification at a Time
>
> Each time the custom resource your controller is watching changes, the reconcile loop will run again. That includes changes done by a user but also changes you do in the Reconcile function or its subroutines. Often you need to update the custom resource you’re operating on to add information. An example from the GCP Project Operator is the ID of the project it created in GCP. This update will cause the reconcile loop to pick up the updated version of the custom resource and start another run of Reconcile.
>
> You need to be aware of this, as changing the custom resource and proceeding in processing can result in race conditions with the newly created request. If parallel processing is enabled, it immediately starts running the Reconcile function. In this case, you must consider there could be a second request working on this resource at the same time in each line of your code. Even if requests are not processed in parallel, reconcile requests will pile up when updating a CustomResource over and over again, keeping the operator unnecessarily busy.
>
> To lower the risk of race conditions and to avoid piling up requests, make sure you don't perform multiple changes to your custom resource or dependent actions in a single run of Reconcile. Whenever you update the custom resource you're watching, just exit the reconcile loop, and let the next run continue. All your idempotent functions executed before will do nothing, and you can continue where you left off.

---

So if I understand correctly, you can make several changes in one run of reconcile function but its generally considered as bad practise.

Comment: @HellowWorld Thanks for reply, however I experienced that I can't use `Update` api several times in reconcile function. Is that special case? or not?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, what errors? @jwl1993